# HTML: href to index page with clean url

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, indexing, href

I have my button that targets to `index.html`, but after I click them, my url above is `domainname.lt/index.html`, but all I want is `domainname.lt`. What should I do? I have no knowledge what to search. I'm using 'href' attribute.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP with the $base_url global variable. Here is a good tutorial on how to use it: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7

Hope this is what you mean :D

Answer (score 0):

Both domainname.lt/index.html & domainname.lt will display the same. If needed peculiar,

your link should be like this:

[link](http://www.domainname.lt)

Answer (score 0):

Use full url or set it  to a variable as global.

$GLOBALS['a'] = 'domainname.lt';